# Deploy to a different environment depending on the source branch

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set environment in the Azure DevOps build pipeline conditionally based on the trigger branch.

I tried something like this:

```
jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'DEV') }}: 
        environment: DEV
      ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'TEST') }}: 
        environment: TEST
```

however no luck.

Any ideas how to set it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build.SourceBranch will contain `refs/heads/` in front of the branch name:

> Git repo branch: `refs/heads/master`
>
> Git repo pull request: `refs/pull/1/merge`

If you want just the final name part (after the last `/`), use `Build.SourceBranchName`.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Yeah, that's it! I do not know how I missed that one.. Thank you